# Why coverage doesn't report anything on Djangos views.py?

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing, coverage.py

I have a class based view in a Django app that looks something like this :

```
class CBView(View):

    def get(self, request, client, *args, **kwargs):
        output1 = self.method1(argument1)
        output2 = self.method2(argument2)
        # Rest of the method implementation
        ...

        return response

    def method1(self, argument1):
        # Implementation
        ... 

        return output1

    def method2(self, argument2):
        # Implementation
        ...

        return output2
```

And I'm trying to write unit tests for the 'easy' class methods, namely `method1` and `method2`. The tests looks like this :

```
class TestCBView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.view = CBView()

    def test_method1(self):
        # Testing that output1 is as expected
        ...
        output1 = self.view.method1(argument1)
        ...
        self.assertEquals(output1, expected_output1)

    def test_method2(self):
        # Testing that output2 is as expected
        ...
        output2 = self.view.method2(argument2)
        ...
        self.assertEquals(output2, expected_output2)
```

After that, I run:

```
coverage run ./manage.py test django_app.tests.test_cbview
```

Which runs all the tests successfully, then I try to run:

```
coverage report -m django_app/views.py
```

And I get :

```
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------
No data to report.
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

I'm using Coverage.py, version 4.0.3., Django 1.8.15 and Python 2.7.13.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051070/why-doesnt-coverage-py-properly-measure-djangos-runserver-command

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. It appeared I had some not migrated data, so after I ran in the terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and I tried again with

```
coverage html --include=django_app/views.py
coverage run manage.py test django_app.tests
```

everything was already fine.

Answer (score -1):

When running tests with `coverage` it generates the `.coverage` file which is in a private format and not intended to be read directly. This file contains the raw reports which will be used to show the report for you, either on console or in html format with `coverage html`. So normally if the tests were ran, the `.coverage` file must be there in the directory from which you launched the command `coverage run ./manage.py test django_app.tests.test_cbview` and then being under that directory, you can hit `coverage report ...` and should work.

Comment: The `django_app/tests/test_cbview.py` path is not in the `.coverage` file :(

Comment: it is not a problem, after you run tests look for that '.coverage' and cd to the location and run 'coverage report -m path_to_your_test'.
In your case, you should find '.coverage' in the same directory as 'manage.py'

Comment: I found the `.coverage` file, I opened it with vim (yeah, yeah, I know, I shouldn't do that :D) and searched for the path of the test (`django_app/tests/test_cbview.py`) and the search came up empty...

Comment: No @Forryah, you will not find test files paths you will find source codes paths like for example "absolute_path of django_app/views.py" . So it is very easy and simple, go to the directory containing '.coverage' and run 'coverage report' .

Comment: Hehe, I used regex to search for `django_app/views.py` so it really doesn't matter if the path is absolute or relative, I would still get a hit. But I did run `coverage report` and it confirmed what I saw in the `.coverage` file... no `django_app/view.py` there...

Comment: try running all the tests 'coverage run manage.py test' and then run teh report of everything and see if it workds 'coverage report'

Comment: Tried this already... I tried everything... running all the test, running just the test file, running a specific test from the test file, for some reason, coverage just doesn't report on the `views.py` file...

Comment: I tried your code (which is full of errors), I got ERRORs when I ran test (ERRORs not TEST FAILUREs) and even though, I get the report for your module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141518/discussion-between-foryah-and-yahya-yahyaoui).